# Handlebars is saying it's missing the helper?

Tags: express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to render a handlebars template manually server side from express.

```
//get handlebars
var hbs = require('hbs').create({
  svg: require('handlebars-helper-svg'),
  switch: require('../helpers/switch.js'),
  case: require('../helpers/case.js'),
});

console.log(hbs)

//convert each entry to HTML via handlebars
var resultsHtml = results.map(function (tutorial) {
  var template = require('../views/list-item.hbs');
  template = hbs.compile(template);

  return template(tutorial);
});
```

The log of hbs gives this:

```
Instance {
  handlebars: 
   { svg: { [Function] cache: {} },
     switch: [Function],
     case: [Function] },
  cache: {},
  __express: [Function: bound middleware],
  SafeString: undefined,
  Utils: undefined }
```

Which seems like it has the 3 helpers, but it keeps spitting out the error

```
Error: Missing helper: "svg"
```

Unless I remove all the SVGs from the template.

I've used this helper from my main app in app.js like this:

```
var svg = require('handlebars-helper-svg');
hbs.registerHelper('svg', svg);
```

But that doesn't work within my route, either way.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not with the helper, but rather with the template. Require is for javascript files and must have modules.export called in them. For other files you need to use the filesystem object to read the file:

```
fs.readFileSync('./views/list-item.hbs', 'utf8')
```